# PHP function for encrypt / decrypt using openssl

Tags: php, openssl

This is a function that is the building block of one wordpress plugin. I came up with this code after some search but i need to optimize it and get any info from more experienced guys.

```
public static function afz_encrypt_decrypt( $action, $string ) {
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key     = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
    $iv_size        = 16;

    if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $encrypt_iv = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM );
        $output     = openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, 0, $encrypt_iv );
        $output     = base64_encode( $encrypt_iv . $output );
    } else if ( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
        $decrypt_iv = substr( base64_decode( $string ), 0, $iv_size );
        $output     = stripslashes( openssl_decrypt( substr( base64_decode( $string ), $iv_size ), $encrypt_method,
            $secret_key,
            0,
            $decrypt_iv ) );
        if ( false === $output ) {
            $output = $string;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**Update**: The stripslashes is indeed unneeded and i will take it out of context of this function. I need it because wordpress automatically escapes strings regardless if the relevant PHP Setting. See the NOTES section here: [CODEX Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep)

What i still need though is more insight (if possible) to Tim's answer in regards to the security aspect of the source.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the security aspect of this, so you might want to wait for answers on that aspect.

**Function Design**

Your function does too many things (encryption and decryption), making it harder to read than necessary and hard to use.

At a minimum you would need to document it properly, as otherwise, users would need to look at the actual code to use it, which isn't ideal.

But really, it will be much simpler to have two functions:

```
function afz_encrypt($plaintext) {}
function afz_dencrypt($ciphertext) {}
```

If you don't want to duplicate the encryption parameters, saving those in the class may be a good idea.

I would also pass the key to the function instead of hardcoding it in the function itself.

**Return values and error handling**

The return values do not seem that well defined. The function returns:

- false if an invalid action is given
- false if it can't base64 encode on encryption
- the base64 encoded iv if it can't encrypt (meaning the input is lost).
- the encrypted input string if it can't decrypt (and this happens without any warnings by PHP).

There are probably more irregularities, but I think the point is clear: A user cannot figure out what exactly went wrong, and sometimes cannot even tell that something went wrong, which will sooner or later lead to bugs.

You should throw exceptions on invalid input stating what exactly went wrong (eg wrong action, cannot base64 decode, etc), and check the output of all the functions you use.

**Invalid Output**

- why stripslashes? It means that `decrypt(encrypt(plain)) != plain` in some situations (eg `foo'bar`, `a\b`, etc).
- Also, `decrypt(encrypt([empty string])) != [empty string]` and `decrypt(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` because of the issues outlined above.

Comment: Thank you! I will wait for more insights if possible. I added the stripslashes because when i type quotes " in the text, then in the db i am getting an extra slash from php... So i am having a recursive \ problem.....

Comment: @e4rthdog that sounds like a bug in the db code, it definitely shouldn't be fixed here.

Comment: Take a look.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my

Comment: @e4rthdog ah yes, WPs magic quotes are a pain. No idea why they still have it... Anyways, it still definitely should not be handled here, but in the db access/save code, some generic function that fixes WPs magic quotes, or somewhere else that makes sense in the context of your code.

Comment: mmm Probably i can do this on decrypt: $string_unslashed = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $string);